# reCAPTCHA v2 iframe height issues

Tags: iframe, height, recaptcha

I'm having issues with implementing the new version of recaptcha. I have a website on a xampp testing server with a test blog post with a comments section. With the previous recaptcha, there were no issues whatsoever. With this version, the iframe that recaptcha puts over the widget is extremely tall. On other websites that have this implemented, I can inspect and see that the iframe is supposed to be tight to the widget itself. On my site, the iframe is 800 x 4000 pixels, and causes the bottom of the page (below the widget) to stretch very far past the content. See below for links to images showing what I'm talking about:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2dca8656db14d615!41273&authkey=!AJ2RprvIfUDA3YU&ithint=folder%2cjpg

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
/* ReCaptcha Iframe FIX */
iframe {display:none !important;}
header iframe,
section iframe,
footer iframe,
div iframe { display:inline; }
```

The recaptcha is simply:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcyQvkSAAAAAGkr-BA4HkFUCthgf0b8bUhfoEIn"></div>
```

I have the recaptcha api.js script called out in my header. The recaptcha itself actually works: I can submit comments and they populate in my database, and I've also tested failing the recaptcha, and the comments do not populate. It's just the iframe issue that needs to be resolved. I couldn't find anything in my css that would cause this, but I'm pretty new so I'm not entirely sure what to look for.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to "solve" this issue by editing recaptcha's div style as such:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key" style="transform:scale(1); width: 304px"></div>
```